# variable content set by webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, rest

I have a rest service which has a list of Groups each group has a GroupName and on my client side I am trying to add those GroupName's to a list of variable groupbox's (number of groupboxes depends on how many GroupNames there is in my rest Group service) can anyone help with the code?:

```
        string uriGroups = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Group";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroups);
        var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox();
            groupbox.Header = String.Format("Group #{0}", n.Element("GroupName");
            groupbox.Width = 100;
            groupbox.Height = 100;
            groupbox.Margin = new Thickness(2);

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Children.Add(groupbox);
            stackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            MainArea.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        }
```

This isnt correct I am just stuck on how to do it.

EDIT:

```
    public Reports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string uriGroups = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Group";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroups);
        foreach(var node in xDoc.Descendants("Group"))
        {

            GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox();
            groupbox.Header = String.Format("Group #{0}", node.Element("Name")); 
            groupbox.Width = 100;
            groupbox.Height = 100;
            groupbox.Margin = new Thickness(2);

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Children.Add(groupbox);
            stackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            MainArea.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        }

    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
            action(item);

        return enumerable;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You shouldn't be using the LINQ `Select` extension to iterate over the collection and do something; it should only be used to transform the element into a new form. If you want to do something like this, either just use a `foreach` statement, or make a new LINQ extension to work on the enumerable like so:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
  {
       foreach(var item in enumerable)
           action(item);

       return enumerable;
  }
```

2) The above code shouldn't compile because it's syntactically broken. What you're attempting to do is make a new anonymous type (the `new { }`). Since you're not making properties on this object, and instead trying to execute random lines of code (which is not allowed), this is not valid. When making an anonymous type, you would do something like this:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { Number = x });
 // Creates a series of 10 objects with a Number property
```

3) It sounds like you just need to refactor your code to the appropriate code to get this done. I'm not seeing the particular problem you are having, other than the non compiling part.

Comment: Hey yeah I am just stuck on the code, Im not sure how to implement what you have said :S

Comment: For example, instead of using `Select`, simply make a `foreach(var node in xDoc.Descendents("Group"))` and then use `item` instead of `n` in your code.

Comment: but system.Linq doesnt contain a definition for Descendents?

Comment: I'm just using the code you provided. In your OP, you have code that implies `XDocument` contains a `Descendents` method.

Comment: sorry it was a spelling mistake, I actually just spent ages figuring out why that wasnt working.... I need a break.

Comment: The `Enumerable.Range` call was just an example of how to use the `Select` extension. You shouldn't use that.

Comment: In addition, you called your iterator variable `node`, not `item`. Use `node` in your code, since that is what you used.

Comment: I get an error when trying this: `Error Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

Comment: Correct, you don't really need that method since you are using the `foreach` statement.